# kubernetes coredns is in CrashLoopBackOff status with "no nameservers found" error

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, kubeadm

I have tried to build kubernetes using kubeadm on my bare-metal server with containerd as cri, but it seemed that coredns failed to start after installing cni (weave-net).

Two coredns containers are now in "CrashLoopBackOff" state, and the logs of them are:

```
plugin/forward: no nameservers found
```

And the description of "kubectl describe pod" is as follows:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m52s (x9 over 13m)    default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/not-ready: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Normal   Scheduled         4m7s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-58cf647449-8pq7k to k8s
  Normal   Pulled            3m13s (x4 over 4m6s)   kubelet            Container image "localhost:5000/coredns:v1.8.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           3m13s (x4 over 4m6s)   kubelet            Created container coredns
  Normal   Started           3m13s (x4 over 4m6s)   kubelet            Started container coredns
  Warning  Unhealthy         3m13s                  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.32.0.3:8181/ready": dial tcp 10.32.0.3:8181: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff           2m54s (x12 over 4m5s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

If I add some settings like "nameserver 8.8.8.8" on /etc/resolv.conf, coredns pods starts running. However, currently I don't use any external dns at all, and with Docker as cri, the coredns worked well though there was no settings on /etc/resolv.conf.

Is it possible to deal with this problem without setting some upstream dns server on resolv.conf?

Server information:

```
OS: RedHat Enterprise Linux 8.4
cri: containerd 1.4.11
cni: weave-net 1.16
tools: kubeadm, kubectl, kubelet 1.22.1
```

I have tried using calico as cni as well, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause was that coredns has a forwarding setting on its ConfigMap by default. It was trying to forward requests to upstream DNS server though there's no DNS setting on /etc/resolv.conf.

```
# kubectl edit configmap coredns -n kube-system
```

After deleting the following section, it started and worked properly.

```
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
```

Comment: I added a bogus IP that my systems /etc/resolv.conf as a nameserver that I couldn't hit to solve this when deploying k3s ahead of time. nameserver 8.8.8.8 pretty much.

Comment: @IT_User Does that work even if there is no internet connection?

Comment: @Diago, yes it does.

Comment: why this works? It will not forward the traffic to host dns?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the following section in coredns configmap :

```
forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
   max_concurrent 1000
}
```

to this:

```
forward . 8.8.8.8 {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

We had a slightly more complex setup where the cluster can be installed in an environment with or without a nameserver. The disadvantage of using a pre-configured nameserver (`8.8.8.8`) that can't be reached is that there is a timeout of about 5 seconds, so we opted for a "dummy" nameserver that immediately throws an error.

```
forward . /etc/resolv.conf 127.0.0.1:9999 {
   max_concurrent 1000
   policy sequential
}
```

We decided to use `172.0.0.1:9999` because we know that coredns itself doesn't expose this port and therefore all requests to this port will be rejected immediately. We also used the `sequential` policy to ensure that we first try to resolve the domain via `/etc/resolv.conf`. Only if that fails we use the "dummy" nameserver and generate an error.